# Finding row from Active record has_and_belongs_to_many association for given object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shops
 end

 class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
 end
```

I have to find the row from join table users_shops associated with user object

can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new model for `UserShop`

```
class UserShop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

Then for some `user` you can do

```
user_shops = UserShop.where(:user_id => user.id)
```

you can also add a relation directly to `UserShop` from `User`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shops
  has_many :user_shops
end
```

and given some `user`, you can do

```
user_shops = user.user_shops
```

Comment: but I am using  has_and_belongs_to_many association, which manages join table in the background and you are telling me to add another model in between. Will User.shops << some_shop_object will add object to UserShop as well ??

Comment: `UserShop` is simply an interface within Rails to an already existing `user_shops` table in your database. `User.shops << some_shop_object` will behave no differently with the existence of this model.

Comment: The existence of the model, for your purposes currently, only serves as an API for you to use to query the `user_shops` table; nothing more.

Comment: but, my join table only contains only shop_id and user_id; no time stamps at all. Then how come UserShop model can save object over it?

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I have to keep a track of how many time user visits the shop, for that purpose I need exact row in the join table, may be I have to add some extra attribute on it like date. What you suggest, whether I have to go for has_may: through or has_many_and_belongs_to_work in my case.

Comment: If you need a timestamp, add a `:created_at` and `:updated_at` column to the `UserShop` model. Then you can add those conditions to the `.where()` mentioned in my answer above.